# Having trouble with custom python module (NameError)

Tags: python, oop

I have been using Python for scripting for a while. By one of my larger projects required that I break down my code into modules. I will describe the scenario below.

Currently, I have two modules. Module A and Module B.

Module A is a class which is used to store data about an objects attributes. It also consists of a number of useful functions which help with parsing the data.

Module B is a very simple helper class with a number of parsing functions which are user-defined.

The way things are set up now, the user has to import Module A and B separately and create a list of all the function objects in Module B. This list of functions is added to Module A by passing it as an attribute to the method **A.add_parser()**. This method sets the functions from B as attributes of A using the function name.

Now, all of this works great and I have tested it. The problem is that one of the parsing functions call for the use of the RegEx module **re**. I am getting a

```
NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

I separately imported the **re** module and am still getting this error. I am familiar with the  **LEGB** rule and since **re** is present in the *global* scope, I do not understand why I am getting this error.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Global is module-global. Did you `import re` in the module that needs it?

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

only need to import the library, before the usage

import re

m = re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')

m.group(0)

'def'